# Razorenginen Not loading View

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using razorengine to send emails. The senden is not the problem, but the content is only displayed as /da/Property/Property/Mail/TellAFriendTextMail in the content.

```
private void SendTellAFriendMail(NotificationTellAFriend mailData)
    {

      string textmail = this.GetMailAsText(mailData);
      string htmlmail = this.GetMailAsHTML(mailData);

      MailAddress from = new MailAddress("robot@mail.com", mailData.SenderName);
      MailAddress to = new MailAddress(mailData.receiverMail, mailData.SenderName);

      using (AlternateView htmlview = this.CreateView(htmlmail, "text/html"))
      using (AlternateView textview = this.CreateView(textmail, "text/plain"))
      using (MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to))
      {
        email.Subject = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Resources.Resources._MailSubject, mailData.SenderName);
        email.AlternateViews.Add(textview);
        email.AlternateViews.Add(htmlview);
        email.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(mailData.receiverMail, mailData.SenderName));

        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
          client.Send(email);
        }

      }
    }

 private string GetMailAsHTML(NotificationTellAFriend mailData)
    {
      return Razor.Parse(Url.Action("/Property/Mail/TellAFriendTextMail"), mailData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the `Razor.Parse` method is not an url but the actual Razor contents that you want to be parsed. So:

```
private string GetMailAsHTML(NotificationTellAFriend mailData)
{
    var razorTemplateFile = Server.MapPath("~/Property/Mail/TellAFriendTextMail.cshtml");
    var razorTemplate = File.ReadAllText(razorTemplateFile);
    return Razor.Parse(razorTemplate, mailData);
}
```

Comment: It's giving me this error "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\SubVersion\Oline\Oline.Portal\Source\Oline.Portal\Property\Mail\TellAFriendTextMail.cshtml'."

Comment: Well what exactly do you expect me to tell? Fix your path so that it is pointing to an existing Razor template.

Comment: Well the path is "Server.MapPath("~/Property/Mail/TellAFriendTextMail.cshtml"

Comment: Sorry but I don't really see how I can help you any further. The first argument of the `Razor.Parse` must contain the Razor markup you want to be parsed. So make sure you have passed a correct path to the `File.ReadAllText` to a template that actually exists on your hard drive at the specified location. Also make sure that the account you are running your application under has sufficient read permissions to the aforementioned template.

Comment: Embarrassingly the solution was that i missed an /View/ in front of the path. But i works perfectly. Thank you so much.